# Is Arc Welder affected by today's announcement that Chrome apps are going away?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-arc

Today Google announced that by 2018 Chrome apps will no longer work on Windows/Macs/Linux.  Does this mean the end of Arc Welder or is Arc Welder more of an extension?  If it's an app, is there any word if it will get migrated to be an extension instead?

Comment: Wipe them out. All of them.

Comment: ?  The difference in capabilities between an app and an extension is pretty stark, so if chrome apps end, a high effort would potentially need to be made to port ARC Welder to an extension.  For what is a developer's tool, not sure it'l happen.

Comment: Why the lack of love for this question - seems highly relevant?

Answer (score 1):

At least App Runtime for Chrome (ARC) is referred to as an "extension" [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mfaihdlpglflfgpfjcifdjdjcckigekc).

Comment: Yeah.  Shows up in Chrome://apps though.  I think that makes it an app.  I have to look at the manifest but I believe it's an app.  The difference in capabilities between an app and an extension is pretty stark, so if chrome apps end, a high effort would potentially need to be made to port it to an extension.